Simulation of a keyboard input of Ascii code with the key combination alt and the numbers
My problem is that i have too simulate the keyboard entry of an ascii code for A as exsample
Here is my code the strange think is that the code with out the alt can type 065 into my editor but if i use the alt key it fucks up.
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);

public const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;
public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;
public const int VK_MENU = 0x12; // Alt key
public const int VK_NUMPAD0 = 0x60; // Numpad 0
public const int VK_NUMPAD6 = 0x66; // Numpad 6
public const int VK_NUMPAD5 = 0x65; // Numpad 5
public const int VK_NUMLOCK = 0x90; // Num Lock key

public void SimulateAltNumpad()
{
    // Press the Num Lock key to activate it
    keybd_event(VK_NUMLOCK, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_NUMLOCK, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);

    // Press the Alt key
    keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);

    // Press and release the Numpad 0 key
    keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD0, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD0, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);

    // Press and release the Numpad 6 key
    keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD6, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD6, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);

    // Press and release the Numpad 5 key
    keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD5, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD5, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);

    // Release the Alt key
    keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}

I want to simulate the entering of the key A by sending the holding alt + 065 to get A into my editor

I believe you need to specify the right or left alt-keys: 0xA4 or 0xA5. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

Hello i tried the public const int VK_MENU = 0xA5; and public const int VK_MENU = 0xA4; but it still do not work
